# For bubbling to work, does the child element even need to have an eventListener on it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm surprised clicking on a list-item executes the event handler. I presume what's happening is a result of bubbling.

```js
function targetHandler(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
}

let list = document.getElementById("myList");
list.addEventListener("click", targetHandler);
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I was aware for an 'event' (i.e.`'click'`) done on an element (that has an event handler for the event) all ancestors of the element that have event handlers for the same event (`'click'`) (and whose 'capture' argument is set to `false`) also execute.

Now I feel like revising it to: for an 'event' done on our child element (that does **or doesn't** have an event handler for the event) all ancestors of the element that have event handlers for the same event done to the child element (`'click'`) (and whose 'capture' argument is set to `false`) also execute.

Comment: what do you want the results to be when you click on `li` ? You forget to mention your expected output.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I don't necessarily want anything - just wanted to understand why the event handler was run (`<li>` was clicked on - not `<ul>`); if it had anything to do with bubbling and if so, how to revise my understanding of bubbling.

Comment: Bubbling happens whether there are event listeners or not. It's not like the browser makers bother checking every ancestor node in the tree before triggering an event; it's a trivial thing to have each node receive an event from its descendants and pass it on if it has no listeners. You could get philosophical and as "if an event happens and no one is listening, did it really happen", but I haven't dropped that kind of drug in a long time ;).

Comment: @HereticMonkey haha make a reacquaintance with it. My understanding of how capturing and bubbling works isn't fully complete cause I can't really understand what you're saying but I think what you've said confirms the last paragraph in my post.